# Film connections

Tags: movies, connect-wall

The set of sixteen films below can be partitioned. Each partition is of four films that have something in common. I invite you to figure out the partitions and commonalities. You'll find that the four commonalities have, themselves, something in common.

- *Baby Driver* (2017)
- *Beautiful Boy* (2018)
- *Blue Velvet* (1986)
- *Bunny Lake Is Missing* (1965)
- *Caned* (2015)
- *Chu Chu and the Philly Flash* (1981)
- *Dazed and Confused* (1993)
- *Hacksaw Ridge* (2016)
- *Hester Street* (1975)
- *Idle Hands* (1999)
- *Lightning Lariats* (1927)
- *Maria's Lovers* (1984)
- *Skidoo* (1968)
- *The Barbarians* (1987)
- *The Hows of Us* (2018)
- *Zachariah* (1971)

Hint added later:

> Three of the partitions relate to the films' titles; one partition requires knowledge of the films beyond their titles.

Hint added even later: Two of the partitions are

> "this film's title has a word with…".

Another partition is

> "this film's title is…".

And the last is

> "this film starred…".

Comment: 4 of them start with B...

Comment: What is fair game for connections? Is knowledge of, say, the plot, or the actors, or the crew, required?

Comment: @bobble, I did tag this with [the "movies" tag](/tags/movies/info). That said, the knowledge required is not particularly arcane. Nothing to do with, say, the gaffer.

Comment: @bobble, see my edit to the question post.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I managed to come up with the following groups:

> Group 1: This film's title has a word with "aria"
>  1) Lightning L**aria**ts
>  2) M**aria**'s Lovers
>  3) The Barb**aria**ns
>  4) Zach**aria**h

> Group 2: This film starred an actress with the name Carol.
>  1) Bunny Lake is Missing (Carol Lynley) 
>  2) Chu Chu and the Philly Flash (Carol Burnett) 
>  3) Hester Street (Carol Kane) 
>  4) Skidoo (Carol Channing)

> Group 3: This film's title is named after a song (corrected by OP). 
>  1) Beautiful Boy - John Lennon 
>  2) Blue Velvet - Bobby Vinton 
>  3) Dazed and Confused - Jake Holmes 
>  4) Baby Driver - Simon and Garfunkel

> Group 4: This film's title contains a word that is an anagram for a music genre type. 
>  1) **Caned** -> Dance [Dance Music] 
>  2) **Idle** Hands -> Lied [Lied Music, a particular type of German music] 
>  3) The **Hows** of Us -> Show [Show Music - as in the kind that plays in shows] 
>  4) Hacksaw **Ridge** -> Dirge [A somber song expressing grief, normally played during funerals.]

As mentioned in the question, "the four commonalities themselves have something in common".

> The common concept is **MUSIC**:
>  1) Aria - A long song accompanying a solo voice. Usually in an opera context.
>  2) Carol - A religious folk song or a popular hymn. Like Christmas carols.
>  3) Song names 
>  4) Anagram of music genres

Comment: @msh210 rot13(Bu, jura V vavgvnyyl frnepurq sbe Onol Qevire fbat anzr, nyy V tbg jnf gur zbivr'f fbhaqgenpx. Juvpu vf jul V chg Vqyr Unaqf gurer vafgrnq. Nyfb, Qvetr jnf pbeerpg)?

Comment: rot13(Lrnu, qvetr jnf zl vagragvba.)